# how to copy files on a differnt ubuntu machine on network to local ubuntu machine

Tags: scp

I am trying to copy files from a ubuntu machine(with IP 10.46.57.44) on to current directory on my ubuntu VMware player using following command but the command doesnt look right?
can anyone suggest what is the right command?

```
scp username@10.46.57.44:/local/mnt/workspace/kernel_db/new/linux-headers-3.10.0+_3.10.0+-10.00.Custom_i386.deb
```

Answer (score 1):

If you type `scp` you will see this:

```
usage: scp [-12346BCpqrv] [-c cipher] [-F ssh_config] [-i identity_file]
           [-l limit] [-o ssh_option] [-P port] [-S program]
           [[user@]host1:]file1 ... [[user@]host2:]file2
```

So, correct syntax is `scp file/to/copy username@0.0.0.0:/where/to/copy/`

But, to use `scp` you need to make sure that ssh server is working on host machine. You can try that with simple `ssh username@0.0.0.0` where `0.0.0.0` is IP address where you want to connect.

Comment: if ssh is not running on the hostname(hostmachien is the one /where/to/copy),how to get it running?

Comment: `sudo apt-get install ssh` should do it, but it is probably installed by default.

Answer (score 0):

For example,

scp username@10.46.57.44:/local/mnt/workspace/kernel_db/new/linux-headers-3.10.0+_3.10.0+-10.00.Custom_i386.deb `<destionation>`

`scp username@10.46.57.44:/local/mnt/workspace/kernel_db/new/linux-headers-3.10.0+_3.10.0+-10.00.Custom_i386.deb root@10.46.57.45:/destination_folder`

HTH!